# Facebook integration in iphone OS 4.0 or later

Tags: iphone, ios4, sdk, facebook

i am trying to integrate Facebook on my iphone OS 4.0. The problem comes when i try to display dialog box for login. the dialog box loads and then crashes immediately.The same code is working great in IOS 3.1. Please help.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my iPhone app. Most likely JavaScript is crashing your application.

I worked around this issue by accessing Facebook login site directly via URL:
http://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=http://YOUR_SITE_URL&scope=publish_stream,offline_access&type=user_agent&display=touch

If you open that link in your iPhone app, it'll display a login screen if user is not logged in, or ask for permission to Publish Stream & Offline Access (as directed in scope) and then it'll come back to YOUR_SITE_URL with access_token, which you can later use to communicate with Facebook via Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of issues related to app crashes, you might want to use the debugger and post the problematic codes for review.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the latest version of the [Facebook SDK from Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk). And please post the code that is crashing.